# How can I access child object property in Compas Search framework?

Tags: search, grails, lucene, grails-plugin, compass-lucene

I have following code (in grails and Searchable Plugin aka Compass):

```
class Topic {

  String name;
  static searchable = true;
}

class Question extends BaseEntity {
  String question;

  static searchable = true;
  static hasMany = [
      topics: Topic
  ]
}
```

How can I search Question with specific topic id?

Something like Question.search("topics#id:12") or Question.search("topics.id:12") dosnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chage your searchable block in Question so it looks like this:

```
static searchable = {
    topics component: true
}
```

and in Topic if you dont want Topics returned as root search elements

```
static searchable = [
    root: false
]
```

Fire up grails and add a few items, then download Luke from http://www.getopt.org/luke/
and open the index for your Question domain object which will be at ~/.grails/projects/projName/searchable-index/'env'/index/question

If you check the documents tab you will see the terms embedded in the index which will be something like $/Question/topics

This should give you the path to put in your Question.search, something like:

Question.search('$/Question/topics/id:1')